# Theme not working for hook_menu page

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have created a simple module with a hook_menu

```
function course_list_menu() {
   $items['course-list'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example Page',
    'page callback' => 'course_list_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
 return $items;
}

  function course_list_page() {
   print '<h1>WILL BE UP SOON </h1>';
   print '<h3>this page is getting build<h3>';
  }
```

As i saw in examples on youtube and some other sites, this text should come in the content region when i visit the link ( with header and footer ). But in my case it is coming in a blank page 
Am i missing some thing ?
How can i display this content int the content region.

My current output is like http://prntscr.com/bpff9q

- using bootstrap theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return something that Drupal can work with and apply to the template files.

Try this:

```
function course_list_page() {
  return array('#markup' => '<h1>WILL BE UP SOON </h1><h3>this page is getting build<h3>');
```

}